# ModuleNotFoundError in DOCKER, even though the module is present

Tags: python, docker

file structure

```
    .
    |
    |-app
      |
      |-main.py
      |-model.py
      |-database.py
    |-Dockerfile
    |-requirements.txt
```

when i run this in docker it says that model not found. and gives me a module import error.

this is my Dockerfile

```
    # 
    FROM python:3.9

    # 
    WORKDIR /code

    # 
    COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

    # 
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

    # 
    COPY ./app /code/app

    # 
    CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

what am i doing wrong? please help.

Comment: Try to switch directly to the `app` directory via `WORKDIR /code/app` and run uvicorn with `"main:app"`

Comment: What's the actual error?  If it's related to a Python module import, what is the relevant `import` statement?